# How to examine various resource types?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a better var_dump()    (please don't suggest alternatives; there is a reason - for me - why I am doing so).

Any hints as to how to display [the various resource types](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php)?

Comment: As far as I know a resource in PHP are very opaque and there's no way to arbitrarily get its properties beyond calling the functions specifically intended for interacting with its resource type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of the resource using [`get_resource_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php), which will give you something like "domxml document". Beyond that it entirely depends on the kind of resource. Every resource is different, there's no standard way to "output" a resource. You could output gd resources using the image functions, you could print the structure of a DOMXML resource by looping through it, you could... dump the database for mysql resources...? Print a list of files for an FTP resource...?

Either you handle each resource individually with custom code, or you just take its type and leave it at that.

Comment: Yup, that's what I feared. Thanks